# How to loop over refreshing a webpage each time I finish processing some data?

Tags: firefox, selenium, python-3.x

I launch Firefox with the URL of a webpage that uses HTTP basic authentication with Selenium. Once I log in, I see only one line of text that is read from a database to which I can not access. So I retrieve that line of text and save to a text file. 
I need to refresh the page using Selenium in order to get the next text line from the database displayed on the page, and I save it again. All this I did it. But I do not know how to refresh the page (looping over the refresh process) after I read each line until the end of the database. Here is my code (valid for the 2 first lines only):

```
from selenium import webdriver
profile=webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('network.http.phishy-userpass-length','255')
driver=webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get("https://my_username:my_password@my_websitew.com/page.php")
r=driver.find_element_by_xpath("html").text
with open('urls.txt','a') as f:
    f.write(r)
```

How can I resolve my problem ?

Comment: How often do you need to refresh the page and how often is new data appearing?

Comment: @alecxe Once a line is displayed, I save it to a text file. I do further treatment on that line later (but let us say I just need to save it to the text file). ONLY after saving is done, I must refresh the page to get the next line. And so on.

Comment: put it in a standard control-flow loop like `while` or `for`, and use `driver.refresh()`

Comment: @alecxe to sum up: the new data (a url) appears only when I refresh the page. And I must refresh after saving the URL to a text file.

Comment: @Begueradj okay, do you need to ever stop refreshing and saving? :)

Comment: @sircapsalot yes, i will need to loop over this process, but I have a trouble about the condition of stopping it. I must not stop until the database is fully read (there is a PHP script behind the page that reads the database and siplays me only one line of text, a URL).

Comment: @alecxe in practice, I do not need to stop at all, but for a special condition, I want to stop refreshing the page once the data base of URLs is wholly displayed by the page to which i authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the logic into the `while` loop and check if the page was changed after the latest hit:

```
latest_content = None
while True:
    driver.refresh()
    new_content = driver.find_element_by_xpath("html").text
    if new_content != latest_content:
        with open('urls.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(new_content)
            latest_content = new_content
```

Comment: simple and efficient idea, indeed :) You are always smarter than me :) Thank You Alexander.

Comment: @Begueradj I hope this works for you or at least put on the right track. You would probably need to exit the loop somehow also.

Comment: Do not worry, I know the number of records in that database, so I only will add a counter to your loop  as a condition :)

Comment: In fact, I do not give the real context of my application (i am not allowed to do that), so I simplify as much as I can my real needs through question that may sound sometimes bad ones. But it is like you read in my mind: this solution is exactly what i need in the real context, by adding a condition of mine (a counter)

Comment: I tried your solution (with adaptation to my real needs) and it works perfectly. Thank you again and sorry for disturbing you with an other comment. Regards